# Printing a C string in reverse without using pointers?

Tags: c, string, reverse

Is there a way to print a string of fixed size in reverse without using pointers?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
char buffer[10];

scanf("%s", buffer);

// need to print buffer in reverse without using pointers?? 

}
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Technically, you've already used a pointer - `buffer` in this code is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element when it is evaluated to be passed to `scanf()`.

Comment: If this is indeed homework, it's a shame they're trying to teach C without the use of pointers.

Comment: Try turning your monitor around to face the other direction, then use a normal `printf`.

Comment: Thank you @caf, you already used pointers!  Its funny because its TRUE

Comment: You can answer the question without using explicit pointers.

Answer (score 8):

A lovely K&R function to reverse your string in-place before printing it, perhaps?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strrev(char *s) {
  int tmp, i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    tmp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = tmp;
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[10];
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  strrev(buffer);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do it with XORs and you have a classic interview question/answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  char buffer[10];

  int n = scanf("%s", buffer);

  // print the number of chars written to buffer
  if (n != EOF) {
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    if (len <= 10) {
      int i;
      for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);  
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 for giving an answer without any comment and that doesn't take into account the fact that the string that is read might be shorter than 9 characters. If you answer homework-type questions answer them correctly and such that the OP at least has a chance to learn something.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of input items assigned (here EOF, 0 or 1), not the length of the string.

Comment: @Key, but but but OMG the `[]` is a syntax sugar for the pointer arithmetic!!! Proper answer probably should be "you can't do it in C without pointer". BTW you miss the 0th (the very first) character in the `buffer`. It should be `i >= 0`, not `i > 0`, in the loop.

Comment: @Dummy: Thank for the loop error. About the pointers I interpreted it as not wanting to use the asterisk sign '*', but instead solve it by indexing the array. Although it very seldom happens, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Jens:  Or answer them incorrectly so that the OP learns to either (A) own up to it being homework or (B) pull out their textbook and read it.

Answer (score 5):

Since `[]` is just syntactic sugar for pointers, here's a version that works completely without pointers, arrays or anything else, just one single `int`. You didn't say that the string has to be stored somehow. :) (Note that I use `fgetc` instead of a buffer and `scanf`).

```
[jkramer/sgi5k:.../c]# cat rev.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_print();

int main(void) {
        fputs("Enter your string, yo! ", stdout);

        read_print();

        fputs("\nDone!\n", stdout);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void read_print() {
        int c = fgetc(stdin);

        if(c != EOF && c != '\n') {
                read_print();
                fputc(c, stdout);
        }
}
[jkramer/sgi5k:.../c]# gcc -o rev rev.c -Wall -W -Os
[jkramer/sgi5k:.../c]# ./rev 
Enter your string, yo! foobar
raboof
Done!
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive way of doing it; technically, this is using a pointer, but I wouldn't go into language-lawyer mode with such simple tasks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* If you want it printed forward, or backward, or think of another way.. */
typedef enum {
    FRONT = 1,
    BACK,
} direction;

/* Technically still using a pointer...don't nitpick. */
void echo_string(char buffer[], size_t buflen, direction from)
{
    /* An index into the buffer to echo, which will preserve
     * its value across subsequent recursive calls.
     */
    static size_t index = 0;
    /* According to the specified direction, print from the front
     * or the back of the buffer. Advance the index (a misnomer, I guess).
     */
    if(from == FRONT) {
        printf("%c", buffer[index++]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", buffer[buflen - ++index]);
    }
    /* Are there any more characters to echo? Yes? Awesome! */
    if(index != buflen) {
        echo_string(buffer, buflen, from);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[10];
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    /* Better strlen() than sizeof() here,
     * but BEWARE! scanf() is DANGEROUS!
     */
    echo_string(buffer, strlen(buffer), BACK);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As caf pointed out, we're still using pointers..!

Here's an other way to solve the problem (of reversing a string). 
This code snippet (and probably most others) don't respect stuff like utf8. I think signines post demonstrating the K&R way was quite close to mine (:D) so I adapted mine to fit that example (and corrected some things..)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strrev(char *s) {

 size_t len = strlen(s) + 1;
 size_t i, j;

 for(i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {

  j = len-1 - i-1;

  char tmp = s[j];
  s[j] = s[i];
  s[i] = tmp;

 }

}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
 char buffer[10];

 scanf("%s", buffer); // Look out for an overflow ;)
 strrev(buffer);
 puts(buffer);

 return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 reverse(char c[], int len)
 {
       if( ! (len / 2))
          return;
       char t =  c[0];   
       c[0] = c[len--];  
       c[len] = t;
       reverse(c, len-1);
 }
```

The error(s) is left as an exercise to the student.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strrev` to reverse a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char buffer[10];

    scanf("%s", buffer);

    strrev(buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually including a comment explaining your method (although one that could be fleshed out a little!) rather than just splurging code.

Comment: -1. `strrev` is non-standard. If you have such a function, it's pure luck, and there's an excellent chance it would be unavailable on the OP's system (whatever it is).

Comment: @Nicholas: Thanks for adding this information. Although it might be better to try using strrev than to implement it on one’s own. For example, the current best answer (for (i = 9…) is not working with strings at all, but with char arrays. If the string terminated at buffer[3] with a null byte, that solution would start dumping arbitrary memory.

Comment: @scytale: I concur that my answer isn't fail-safe. Returned value from scanf should be used to only print the chars set by scanf.

Answer (score 0):

```
void outstrreverse(const char s[])
{
    size_t l=strlen(s);
    while( l && s!=&s[--l] )
        putchar(s[l]);
    if(s[0])
        putchar(s[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the relationship between C strings, arrays, and pointers the exercise is rather shotty IMHO - the most *idiomatic* description of a "String" in C is represented by the char*, which is not an array. Your (the OPs) title and post differ in their definitions between string and char[fixed length].

[The OP should read and understand this FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html), and between that and the posts here: easily figure out a solution—as well as defend it to the teacher/judge if need be.

I'll comment on this: never use scanf("%s", buffer) to populate a fixed length string. If you *must* use scanf() to do it, please use a field width specifier: e.g. scanf("%9s", buffer); if buffer is an [10], you want a specifier of 9 because of how scanf fills the buffer: otherwise you must beware the dragons! You could also scanf by character and evade the issue with a loops bounds, but that would likely be less efficient.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void reverse(char a[], int s, int sc );

void reverse(char a[], int s, int sc ){

if ((sc-s)<(s-1))
{
a[sc-s]^=a[s-1];
a[s-1]^=a[sc-s];
a[sc-s]^=a[s-1];
reverse (a, s-1, sc) ;

}

}

void main (){


char a[]="ABCDEFG";

reverse(a, 7, 7);
printf("%d",a);
getch(); //i just use it to freeze the screen

}
```

Comment: And for using the wrong return type for main, the wrong conversion specifier for printf(), the non-standard conio.h and getch(), no newline in printf(), and the horrible XOR swap "technique".